# assembly: how to extend a float to a double for sin function usage

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, x86, att

The C version functions:

```
float foo1 (float a, float b) 
{
    return sin(a) + b;
}

double sin(double x);
double cos(double x);
```

`cos` is for a later function.
The task is to translate `foo1` to assembly, but as you can see `a` is a `float` and `sin` expects a `double` parameter. Have been translating C to assembly codes for weeks now, but honestly, have no idea of how to do in this point here.

Comment: Compile the C version to asm using `gcc -S` and use the generated code for guidance.

Comment: AT&T is *syntax* - presumably this is an x86 CPU ? In which case 32 bit or 64 bit ?

Comment: That. I'm running it in -m32

Comment: No user, it must be specifically `sin`.

Comment: You probably want to download the Intel manuals, they have a nice instruction reference: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals

Answer (score 3):

gcc is your friend - compiling with `gcc -S` suggests that you might want to use `cvtss2sd` for float to double conversion and `cvtsd2ss` for converting the double result back to float:

```
_foo1:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movss   8(%ebp), %xmm0
    cvtss2sd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%esp)
    calll   _sin
    fstpl   -16(%ebp)
    movss   12(%ebp), %xmm0
    cvtss2sd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    addsd   -16(%ebp), %xmm0
    cvtsd2ss    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, -4(%ebp)
    flds    -4(%ebp)
    addl    $24, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

**EDIT**: this appears to be some kind of homework assignment with arbitrary constraints. If you need to avoid SSE instructions then just add `-mno-sse` to the command line (`gcc -mno-sse ...`) and you get:

```
_foo1:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    flds    8(%ebp)
    fstpl   (%esp)
    calll   _sin
    fadds   12(%ebp)
    fstps   -4(%ebp)
    flds    -4(%ebp)
    addl    $24, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

**EDIT 2**: for more compact code you can omit the stack frame (`gcc -fomit-frame-pointer ...`) - note however that you will lose some functionality when it comes to debugging or profiling:

```
_foo1:
    subl    $12, %esp
    flds    16(%esp)
    fstpl   (%esp)
    calll   _sin
    fadds   20(%esp)
    fstps   8(%esp)
    flds    8(%esp)
    addl    $12, %esp
    ret
```

Comment: Be careful; if you're doing mem-to-reg transfer, you need the `movss` before `cvtss2sd` - `cvtss2sd` from memory to register leaves the most significant 64 bits unchanged. Here is more info on [why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16597686/149530) this is dangerous.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: OK - but this is compiler-generated code, so I'm assuming it's fairly reliable. ;-)

Comment: Yes it is, the `movss` is there. ;-)

Comment: I am not suppose to use more than load/store/arithmetic functions to do this task. Do `cvtss2sd` translates itself in some of those? `push`, `pop` and it's arithmetics included as well.

Comment: OK - if this is some kind of homework assignment with arbitrary constraints then you really ought to specify those in the question so as not to waste people's time. I've updated the answer now. For future reference use a compiler to solve this kind of problem - it's much quicker and more reliable than doing it manually.

Comment: `flds    8(%ebp)
 fstpl   (%esp)` that's seems to be the `sinf` function suggested in the post comments which I also cannot use.

Comment: It is, although you're the only one in a considerable row to feel any problem by that. And it was written it was a TASK from the beginning. You also should read the comments, to not waste mine.

Comment: No - there's a call to the `sin()` function right there in the code: `calll   _sin` - you should probably get yourself an x86 instruction reference guide.

Comment: You're right, gcc is my friend. Can provide good automatic answers. Sometimes that's the best you can get or ever need.

Comment: By the way @PaulR, your code seems to be inefficient - there is no need for reserve 24 bytes in the stack for a single `double`, which could even be used for the following question, but are not - and unsafe - the return address bytes being used to store return value.

Comment: It's not "my" code - it's generated by gcc (actually clang) - if you want to make it more efficient though then try compiling with `-omit-stack-frames`, although you will lose some debug and profiling capability if you do this. Also if you actually care about efficiency then you should be using the single precision `sinf()` - calling `sin()` for doubles is *very* inefficient.

Comment: AAND nothing appears with gcc -S.

Comment: `gcc -S foo.c` will produce an output file named `foo.s`

Comment: @PaulR, +1 for being so patient with the OP.  But what is `-omit-stack-frame`?  I don't find that in GCC.  Do you mean `-fomit-frame-pointer`?  I think that's on by default with `-On`.

Comment: Ah - you could be right - I typed that from memory.

Comment: Now is when you say where the file is @PaulR.

Comment: @Ajna: see above - `gcc -S foo.c` will produce an output file named `foo.s` - if this isn't happening for you then there is something very wrong with your gcc installation.

Comment: W-H-E-R-E. read anything please. I already have a `foo.s` which is the code I'm writing.

Comment: As you would expect with gcc, the default location for the output file is in the same directory as the source file, unless you specify otherwise. So if your current working directory is `/home/test` and you have a source file file there named `foo.c` (i.e. `/home/test/foo.c`) then the output of `gcc -S foo.c` will be `/home/test/foo.s`. This is really basic stuff - you should at least read the man page for gcc and get familiar with the command line switches.