# GCC flag to ignore instruction dependencies

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, decompiling, compiler-flags

[I am trying to decompile a piece of code and apparently gcc prefers less complicated instructions over the more complex ones.](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24980/force-gcc-to-use-more-complex-instructions?noredirect=1#comment38981_24980) After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16597686/5838252) I suspect it's because gcc is trying to reduce instruction dependencies. Is there any way to instruct gcc to ignore these dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

If it's about *decompiling* then it is not GCC's business but Binutils'. Hence check your host's Binutils options whether you can disable printing instructions in their simplified representation.